# How to declare an objective function (Minimize) and it's constraints with upper and lower limits on Python?

Tags: python, optimization, anaconda, linear-programming, pyomo

I have a linear programming problem with 8 variables.How I can generate a set of constraints (equalities and/or inequalities) with upper and lower bounds on Python in order to minimize an objective function?. I am specifically asking to do it with Pyomo solver if possible,if not using any other solver on Python (e.g., Gurobi, Cplex,etc) is fine, I just want to have an idea on how to tackle this problems on Python.

Comment: Have you looked at the Pyomo documentation? https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/

Also Pyomo is not a solver; it’s a modeling environment for mathematical optimization problems. CPLEX, Gurobi, GLPK etc. are solvers.

Answer (score 0):

Very [simple bus and zoo example](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6):

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('cplex')

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.nbBus = pyo.Var([40,30], domain=pyo.PositiveIntegers)

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = 500*model.nbBus[40] + 400*model.nbBus[30])

model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = 40*model.nbBus[40] + 30*model.nbBus[30] >= 300)

results = opt.solve(model)

print("nbBus40=",model.nbBus[40].value)
print("nbBus30=",model.nbBus[30].value)
```